# how can you sort this based on prep time without sorting the first line, in unix with vi or vim?

Tags: unix, vim, vi

```
name;ingredients;diet;prep time;cook time;flavor profile;course;state (region)
Lassi;yogurt,milk,nuts,sugar;vegetarian;5;5;sweet;dessert;Punjab (North)
Papad;urad dal,sev,lemon juice,chopped tomatoes;vegetarian;5;5;spicy;snack;Bihar (South)

...
```

Comment: So many new contributors with CSV questions in Vim…

Answer (score 2):

You might get away with:

```
:2,$sort n
```

- The range `2,$` makes sure you skip the first line.
- The `n` option ensures a numeric sort.

And also from `:help sort`:

> With [n] sorting is done on the first decimal number in the line (after or inside a {pattern} match). One leading '-' is included in the number.

And since `prep time` is the first field containing a decimal number, you get the right result.

(This will fail if you have any `name`, `ingredient` or `diet` containing a number.)